# How to use R to correctly download data from FREDR package

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to run a code in R to get some data from FREDR package but I'm getting trouble to understand the error R shows me.

The code I have:

```
library(fredr)
fredr_set_key("...")
cpi <- fredr::fredr(series_id = "CPIAUCSL",observation_start = as.Date("1960-01-01"),observation_end = as.Date("2005-12-01"))
```

The error I get:

```
Error in (function (endpoint, ..., to_frame = TRUE, print_req = FALSE)  : 
  400: Bad Request.  The value for variable api_key is not a 32 character alpha-numeric lower-case string.  Read https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/api_key.html for more information.
```

This code runs perfectly in the computer of my professor (who is a Windows user) so I think that the problem may be related to my Mac but I'm really not sure.

Mac OS 10.15.4

Comment: You need an api key (basically a password).  Your professor likely has one saved on their computer, which is why the code works there.  If you follow the link in the error message it tells you how to register and request a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use your API key? You should request one here: https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/api_key.html

Then replace `...` with your API key.